# Sync Google Calendar with SQL database (and other way around)?

Tags: php, mysql, gwt, google-calendar-api

I would like a Google Calendar to sync with my SQL database.
I have a database that contains events (in PST timezone), with the fields 'title' (event title), 'date' (event date, day/month/time ie 05/03/2012), 'time' (event start time in 24h ie 03:00 or 23:30), 'end' (event end time in 24h ie 05:00), and 'embed' that contains the event description. All the fields are strings (not int or date/time).

I'd like to have the Google Calendar sync with the information in the database, and also the other way around (if a new event is added to the calendar, add it to the database).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to find an XML parser that will get the Google Cal export however often you need, then submit that to the database. The only problem you will run into with that is redundancy if you don't make the parser check if a similar event is already in the database.